# как написать php код на Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Вопрос, как этот php код написать на Sql

```
$sqlmax = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table2");
$maxid = mysql_fetch_array($sqlmax)["MAX(ID)"]; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1`"); 
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $maxid++;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table2` (`ID`,`name`) VALUES ('".$maxid."','".$result["name"]."')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table3` (`ID`) VALUES ('".$maxid."')");
}
```

Comment: А в table3 точно только id надо записывать, для чего она используется такая странная. Не хотите в table2 ID сделать auto_increment, что бы сам назначался, а не использовать не безопасные методы с max(id) ? И на данный момент в table3 столько же записей сколько в table2, все id присутствуют или каких то может не быть ?

Comment: Объясните поподробней в вопросе что вы делаете с таблицами и как они взаимосвязаны, возможно то что вы делаете можно написать при помощи SQL только понимая вашу задачу

Answer (score 0):

что бы не делать запись

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO`table3`(`ID`) VALUES ('".$maxid."')");` вам надо сделать index `ID` PRYMARY AUTO_INCREMENT - в таком случае он будет увеличиваться на 1 с каждой новой записью и зачем вам содержать таблицу `table3` лишь для этой цели, я не увидел там других столбцов???

В итоге таким же образом можно отказаться в добавлении ID - и в первой таблице - их никто никогда не добавляет подобным образом, потому что индексы уникальны и идет автоинкремент

Будут вопросы - дополню ответ

"да сразу запрос зафигачь"
Если без AUTO_INCREMENT
то

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`ID`,`name`) 
VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(`ID`) FROM `table2`)+1 ,'".$result["name"]."')
```

второй запрос аналогичен

```
INSERT INTO `table3` (`ID`) VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(`ID`) FROM `table2`)+1 )
```

если у вас будет AUTO_INCREMENT, то таблица `table3` вам будет не нужна
и запрос будет

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`name`) VALUES ('".$result["name"]."')
```

Вы хотите использовать цикл в SQLчтобы переписывать значения столбцов из одной таблицы в другую, в таком случае можно поставить под сомнение нормализацию вашей базы данных. О нормализации базы данных можно почитать на вики [Нормализация баз данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Налицо нарушение [Третьей нормальной формы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: да сразу запрос зафигачь, ему же все равно во вторую таблицу вставлять этот id (пока, правда, непонятно зачем)

Comment: Судя по циклу в php коде могу предположить что в table1 записей много и они все переписываются ... Но что либо делать пока автор вопроса не ответит не вижу смысла.

Comment: Я знаю про PRYMARY AUTO_INCREMENT вопрос в другом мне просто надо понять как код, который я написал выше можно написать на sql, т.е. тот же цикл ток на sql. Погуглив я  вроде как понял, что на sql можно писать циклы, ток вот не разобрался с переменными. Например если в php в цикле $result["name"] - это значение столбца name, то как определить это значение также в цикле, ток на sql